# MPI: Waitany is not reacting to ibcast call

Tags: c++, c, mpi

The following code is a Implementation of a Master/Worker pattern.

The Ibcast is used to Terminate all workers, since we do not know the size of the Problem in the beginning of the program.

MPI_Waitany() is used to wait on Irecv for getting new data and Ibcast to terminate the program.

The Problem is that MPI_Waitany is blocking after all MPI_Send() from the master are Received. So MPI_Ibcast() does not return the blocking

```
if (myid == 0) { //Master
    bool test = false;
    MPI_Request mpi_request;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
       //Sending I 1..10 to Worker
       MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
       cout << "Sending: " << i <<  endl;
   }
   cout << "Bcast Worker finished" << endl;
   //Only to show even if the Bcast ist fired after worker is finished.
   sleep(10);
   //Using Ibcast for because Bcast can not Send to Ibcast in worker.
   MPI_Ibcast(&test, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request);

   MPI_Wait(&mpi_request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
   cout << "Root Fin" << endl;

} else { //Worker
   while (true) {
       bool test = true;
       int i = 20;
       MPI_Request mpi_request[2];
       MPI_Ibcast(&test, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request[0]);
       MPI_Irecv(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request[1]);

       int RequestID = 0;

       //Wait passes 10 Times for Send
       //Wait can not pass after work is done.
       MPI_Waitany(2, mpi_request, &RequestID, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
       cout << "The \'I\' i got is: " << i <<" The Boolean is:" << test << endl;
       if (!test)
           break;
   }
}
//OUTPUT
//Sending: 0
//Sending: 1
//Sending: 2
//Sending: 3
//Sending: 4
//Sending: 5
//Sending: 6
//Sending: 7
//Sending: 8
//The 'I' i got is: 0 The Boolean is:1
//The 'I' i got is: 1 The Boolean is:1
//Sending: 9
//Bcast Worker finished
//The 'I' i got is: 2 The Boolean is:1
//Root Fin
//The 'I' i got is: 3 The Boolean is:1
//The 'I' i got is: 4 The Boolean is:1
//The 'I' i got is: 5 The Boolean is:1
//The 'I' i got is: 6 The Boolean is:1
//The 'I' i got is: 7 The Boolean is:1
//The 'I' i got is: 8 The Boolean is:1
//The 'I' i got is: 9 The Boolean is:1
//No more output Programm is not Terminating and stuck in MPI_Waitany();
```

The following is a Simpler Example where the unlock is working.

```
if (myid == 0) {
   bool test = false;
   MPI_Request mpi_request;


   MPI_Ibcast(&test, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request);
   MPI_Wait(&mpi_request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
   cout << "Root Fin" << endl;

} else {
   bool test = true;
   cout << "Value is:" << test << endl;
   int i = 20;
   MPI_Request mpi_request[2];
   sleep(2);
   MPI_Ibcast(&test, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request[0]);
   MPI_Irecv(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request[1]);

   int RequestID = 0;
   sleep(2);
   MPI_Waitany(2, mpi_request, &RequestID, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
   //Should Print 0 in Begining is 1
   cout << "Value is:" << test << endl;
}

//OUTPUT
//Value is:1
//Root Fin
//Value is:0
```

Comment: The worker should `MPI_Ibcast()` **before** entering the `while` loop.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet This is not working since the `MPI_Waitany` is deallocated the request handle and sets it to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`

Comment: Are you saying you fixed your problem ?

Comment: Your program is stuck waiting either 11th send or 11th ibcast. It will complete if you end up waiting either 11th send or 1st ibcast. If you edit your question with a [MCVE] I will post the answer tomorrow.

Comment: No My Problem is not fixed.
The Program should stop as sone as any ibcast is received on a Worker.
The First code Snipped is everything. Here is a link to the Boiler plaid code.
https://gist.github.com/Syndlex/95c0b3490ca3c803f3783cdca21459be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is stuck waiting either 11th send or 11th ibcast. It will complete if you end up waiting either 11th send or 1st ibcast.

Here is my (non tested) answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>


using namespace std;


int myid, numprocs;
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    int namelen;

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (myid == 0) { //Master
        bool test = false;
        MPI_Request mpi_request;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            //Sending I 1..10 to Worker
            MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            cout << "Sending: " << i <<  endl;
        }
        cout << "Bcast Worker finished" << endl;
        //Only to show even if the Bcast ist fired after worker is finished.
        sleep(10);
        //Using Ibcast for because Bcast can not Send to Ibcast in worker.
        MPI_Ibcast(&test, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request);
        MPI_Wait(&mpi_request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        cout << "Root Fin" << endl;

    } else { //Worker
        bool test = true;
        MPI_Request mpi_request[2];
        MPI_Ibcast(&test, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request[0]);

        while (true) {
            int i = 20;
            MPI_Irecv(&i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mpi_request[1]);

            int RequestID = 0;

            //Wait passes 10 Times for Send
            //Wait can not pass after work is done.

            MPI_Waitany(2, mpi_request, &RequestID, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

            cout << "The \'I\' i got is: " << i <<" The Boolean is:" << test << endl;
            if (!test)
                break;
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tank you this is working.

I don't really know why I used a simular code bevor and my MPI_Request was MPI_REQUEST_NULL after the waitany call.
Thanks for the help

Comment: per the MPI spec, the `mpi_request[RequestID]` is set to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL` by `MPI_Wait_any()` unless `RequestID` is `MPI_UNDEFINED`